# Changing table background color through AJAX jquery?

Tags: php, javascript, jquery, html, ajax

**Scenario:** When my web page load automatically search with cell has been input by user and have value. If has been input the table background color will red else will green.

Assume this table has not been input yet. The table background green like this

[image]

and source-code of table:

```
  <table width="1023" height="200" border="1">
      <tr>
        <th colspan="2" scope="col">A1</th>
        <th colspan="2" scope="col">A2</th>
        <th colspan="2" scope="col">A3</th>
       </tr>
    <tr>
        <td bgcolor="#00CC00"><div class="data" align="center" value="A1.4"><input type="button" onclick="popup_window_show('#sample', { pos : 'tag-right-down',   parent : this, width : '270px' });setvalue(this.value);" value="A1.4" /></td>
        <td bgcolor="#00CC00"><div class="data" align="center" value="A1.8"><input type="button" onclick="popup_window_show('#sample', { pos : 'tag-right-down',   parent : this, width : '270px' });setvalue(this.value);" value="A1.8" /></td>
        <td bgcolor="#00CC00"><div class="data" align="center" value="A2.4"><input type="button" onclick="popup_window_show('#sample', { pos : 'tag-right-down',   parent : this, width : '270px' });setvalue(this.value);" value="A2.4" /></td>
        <td bgcolor="#00CC00"><div class="data" align="center" value="A2.8"><input type="button" onclick="popup_window_show('#sample', { pos : 'tag-right-down',   parent : this, width : '270px' });setvalue(this.value);" value="A2.8" /></td>
        <td bgcolor="#00CC00"><div class="data" align="center" value="A3.4"><input type="button" onclick="popup_window_show('#sample', { pos : 'tag-right-down',   parent : this, width : '270px' });setvalue(this.value);" value="A3.4" /></td>
        <td bgcolor="#00CC00"><div class="data" align="center" value="A3.8"><input type="button" onclick="popup_window_show('#sample', { pos : 'tag-right-down',   parent : this, width : '270px' });setvalue(this.value);" value="A3.8" /></td>
    </tr>
    </table>
```

i use ajax.jquery to check cell value like this

```
 var htmlobjek;
     $(document).ready(function () {
         var i = $("td").find("td.data").val();
          $.ajax({
                 url: "cek.php",
                 data: "i",
                 cache: false,
                 success: function (data) {
                     $("#cek").val(data);
                 }
             });     
     });
```

of course in cek.php will like this

```
<?php
$posisi =  $_POST[i];

$val = mssql_num_rows(mssql_query("SELECT*FROM tblTrnProduct WHERE Posisi = '$posisi'"));

echo"$val";
?>
```

to get the output of cek.php. I use a little trick.
I make a

```
<input id="cek" name="cek" type="text" />
```

as a mirror.

After that I manipulate table background with this javascript

```
 $(document).ready(function () {
         $("#cek").change(function () {
             var cek = $("#cek").val();
                 if (cek === 0) {
                     $("td").style("bgcolor", "#00CC00");//green
                     else {
                         $("td").style("bgcolor", "#FF0000");//red

                     }
                 }
            });
     });
```

but nothing happen after user input the data by popup form. Any idea that can help this problem with an example will more appreciate.

Comment: The change event is not triggered when the value is changed programatically with javascript. You would have to trigger a change yourself.

Comment: Be very careful! **Your code is vulnerable to SQL injection.** You shouldn't use values obtained from the user directly into an SQL statement - you should always escape/sanitize the data first.

Comment: @Lix tq for advice. this just for example to make that clear..c'z i still weak in english ..:)

Comment: ok tq for the answer i can change background colour. But i got a problem to record static value. like this
<td bgcolor="#00CC00"><div class="data" align="center" value="A1.4"><input type="button" onclick="popup_window_show('#sample', { pos : 'tag-right-down',   parent : this, width : '270px' });setvalue(this.value);" value="A1.4" /></td>
i try to get record this value with this
 var i = $("td").find("td.data").val();
but this function doesn't got that value..what's the problem...?

Comment: what is `i` here  `$posisi =  $_POST[i];`  ?

Comment: @NullPonyPointer parameter for sql function

Comment: @plalx can you tell with an example?

Comment: @AndriansyahAndri

 `success: function (data, status, xhr) {
     console.log(xhr.responseText);
 }`

Show us what has been output in the console, that will allow us to see what the server has returned.

Comment: @plalx the problem on how to get static value as parameter on sql. Like (var i = $("td").find("td.data").val();) i think this function can get value from( <td bgcolor="#00CC00"><div class="data" align="center" value="A1.4">) so no result in sql(just my think)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Real Solution

```
script type="text/javascript">
    var htmlobjek;
     $(document).ready(function () {
    var ajaxCall = $.ajax({
        url: "cek.php",
        type:'POST',
        data: $('#data').serialize(),
        cache: false,
    }).done( function (data) {
        $("#cek").val(data);
    }).fail( function () {
        alert('I can not send ajax here');
    });

    ajaxCall.done( function (data) {
        var k = $("#cek").val();
        if(k == 0){
            $(".dataa").css("background-color", "#00CC00");//green
        }
        else {
            $(".dataa").css("background-color", "#FF0000");//red
        }
    });
    });
    </script>
```

Answer (score 1):

The brackets on your if-else aren't right, it's like the else is inside the if:

```
if (cek === 0) {
    $("td").style("bgcolor", "#00CC00");//green
         else {
           $("td").style("bgcolor", "#FF0000");//red
          }
 }
```

I think you mean

```
if (cek === 0) {
     $("td").style("bgcolor", "#00CC00");//green
 } else {
     $("td").style("bgcolor", "#FF0000");//red
 }
```

Comment: nothing happen c'z the get value just 0 only. like nothing happen.

Comment: Instead of if (cek === 0), try if (cek == "0")

Answer (score 0):

```
 You can try this,

  if (cek === 0) {
    $("td").css("backgroundColor", "#00CC00");//green
  } else {
    $("td").css("backgroundColor", "#FF0000");//red
  }
```

Answer (score 0):

Include jquery.color.js for CSS background property. If not write new class and apply to TR addClass("newclass")