# Changing table background color through AJAX jquery? (ASK)

Tags: php, javascript, ajax, jquery

before i ask about this problem
[Changing table background color through AJAX jquery?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15831040/changing-table-background-color-through-ajax-jquery)

i can change the background color. but i got another **problem 
my mirror**

```
<input id="cek" name="cek" type="text" />
```

always got value only 0. so the bcakground color cann't change always green.

does my logic correct?
what the best methode for this problem?
please advice

Comment: Update your older question.

Answer (score 1):

You could also do this:

```
$("#cek").css("background-color", "red");
```

Comment: yes...that rigt. my problem now on value of my mirror. always read 0. so table background always green

Answer (score 0):

```
$('#cek').attr('background', {your color});
```